# Area of a cluster with DBSCAN

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I've an array of X and Y coordinates of some points spread in a field. I want to know if these points form clusters.

This coordinate array is a numpy array, where the first column is the X and the second column the Y. Here is an example:

```
>>> ch1_data[0:5]
[[ 11743. 17707.7]  
[ 15850.9 16474. ]  
[ 21205.1 17580.2]  
[ 11763.2 17712.5]  
[ 14094.9 16369.7]]
```

I process it with the DBSCAN algorithm from sklearn.cluster module. The code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

db1 = DBSCAN(eps=20, min_samples=2, metric='euclidean').fit(ch1_data)
db1_labels = db1.labels_
db1n_clusters_ = len(set(db1_labels)) - (1 if -1 in db1_labels else 0)
print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % db1n_clusters_)
labels_ch1 = db1.labels_
ch1_counts = np.bincount(labels_ch1[labels_ch1>=0])
print('Number of particles per cluster:', ch1_counts)
```

Is there a way to get the area of the clusters?

Comment: You have to define the area carefully. Multiple shades can enclose the same set of points. I can even have a star shade that is non-convex. Are you talking about area of the convex hull of the cluster?

Comment: Alpha shapes seem most appropriate. But you'll have to code this yourself.

Comment: @Mai Yes, the area of the convex hull of the cluster will be great. The way of doing the it is with 'scipy.spatial.ConvexHull'?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Certainly, seems that this will give more accurate areas of the clusters, but I think I don't need this degree of accuracy... and I don't know how to code it...

Comment: And `min_samples=2` means that you are not using density, your result will be equivalent to single-linkage hierarchical clustering, cut at height `eps`. So it's not really DBSCAN because of this parameter being too low.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Oh, sorry, thanks for commenting it. I was playing with the values and I copy-paste the code with these values. Normally I use for my data a `min_samples` about 10 and a `eps` about 200. Regarding this issue (values for `eps` and `min_samples`), is there a way to estimate the values? I've seen that epsilon could be estimated using the nearest-neighbor distance, but what about `min_samples`?

Comment: See the DBSCAN paper.